# Storing numerical IDs as Integers or Strings

Tags: database, string, performance, database-design, types

I'm designing an API at the moment which deals with student accounts for multiple schools. The student object has a reference to the school they are assigned to using the school ID, which is just a six digit number. In my design, I'm storing this ID as a string (my preference for identifiers), but my boss said he would prefer it was an integer since it is a number, but that was just his preference.

My question is: What are the pros and cons of storing numerical IDs as strings versus storing them as integers. The few I can think of off the top of my head are:

Pros of using a string:

- More in line with the purpose of the field. The quotation marks make it immediately obvious what the field is for.
- Avoid the admittedly not very high risk of doing any arithmetic on it. The fact that this is *never* going to be something we do suggests that it should be a string.
- No work needs to be done if we want to change the format of the ID in the future (they want to add letters to the end of the ID, for example).

Pro of using an integer:

- More efficient to store the info as an integer. Given modern hardware, unless you are storing a large number of IDs in an environment where storage space is scarce, or processing *needs* to be as efficient as possible, I doubt this would be an issue.

Are there any other factors I should take into consideration when making the string vs integer decision?

Comment: Another possible pro for strings is that if the ID can start with a zero, the string will preserve that.  I get very frustrated when web sites tell me my 5 digit ZIP code is 5361.  It isn't, it's **0**5361!  The leading 0 is significant (although often the people in the post office will fix it, if they actually try and mail me something with that on the envelope).

Comment: That's a great point! I hate putting numerical IDs into spreadsheet programs for this exact reason.

Comment: Indexes on integers are more efficient than indexes on strings.

Comment: The storage size of an int is 4 bytes. a string with 6 chars is at least 6 bytes. that's 1.5 more. Adding the fact that this column should probably be indexed, well, you do the math.

Comment: Another pro for int: keeping the number in a string column will force you to write code to make sure there are only digits in the value (whether it's a check constraint, trigger, or program code). Int column will not allow this kind of data to begin with.

Comment: Thats a good point, but I feel like you should be validating your identifiers pretty strongly anyway.